# manually setting colours for geom_path in ggplot2 without affecting other elements of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given my sample data `new_mtcars` below, I would appreciate any help to manually set colours for `geom_path` based on the variable `new_mtcars$group` giving for example `black` to `group1` and `red` to `group2`.

Below I present my unsuccessful attempt based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42743785/in-r-using-geom-path-with-different-size-and-color-parameters). The problem is that it simply does not apply the colours `black` and `red` I want to `geom_path`.

**#preparing sample data**

```
mtmodel <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
mtcars$Low <- predict(mtmodel, newdata = mtcars, interval = "confidence")[,2]
mtcars$High <- predict(mtmodel, newdata = mtcars, interval = "confidence")[,3]
mtcars$Mean <- predict(mtmodel, newdata = mtcars, interval = "confidence")[,1]
new_mtcars<-tidyr::gather(mtcars, "Variable", "value", Low:Mean)
```

**#creating groups**

```
library(tidyverse)
new_mtcars$group <- ifelse(new_mtcars$wt <= 3.5, "group1", "group2")
new_mtcars <- arrange(new_mtcars, wt)
```

**#drawing the plot with automatic selection of colours for geom_path**

```
ggplot(new_mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=value, linetype=Variable)) +
  geom_path(size = 0.71, aes(colour = group)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cyl))
```

**#my attempt to manually set the colours for geom_path based on levels of group**

```
    #does not work

  ggplot(new_mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=value, linetype=Variable)) +
  geom_path(size = 0.71, aes(colour = group)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = cyl)) 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```

**#my current output, which does not apply the selected colours to geo_path**

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I get black dots only when I run your code.

Comment: Thanks, @markus. Just edited the code and the text accordingly.

Comment: Do you redefine `cyl` as a discrete character or factor somewhere? I get an error with the given code because `group` is discrete, but `cyl` is continuous, and both are being mapped to color.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that relies on defining each of the colors manually. I don't know a way to define only a few and leave the rest to be defined automatically.

```
ggplot(new_mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=value, linetype=Variable)) +
  geom_path(size = 0.71, aes(colour = group)) +
  # In the example, cyl was still numeric, creating an error here,
  #   since group is discrete and ggplot doesn't know how to mix
  #   discrete and continuous variables to the same aesthetic.
  geom_point(aes(colour = as.character(cyl)), shape = 21) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("4" = "blue", "6" = "green", "8" = "purple", 
                                "group1" = "black", 
                                "group2" = "red"))
```

[image]